# Parsing XML returned from cURL and having issues parsing the curl_exec object into a SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, rest, curl, xml-parsing, simplexml

I seem to be getting back a well-formed XML document from this cURL, but I can't seem to parse this return using the SimpleXMLElement class. This is the iteration of code that I'm working with now:

```
$url = "http://rosemary.umw.edu/~stephen/cpsc448/numCredits.php?prefix=". $prefix ."&number=" . $number; // prefix=cpsc&number=220
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

echo $resp;
```

This returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><NumCredits>4</NumCredits>
```

This is how I'm currently trying to parse the return:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);
echo $xml->NumCredits[0];
```

Using this I don't get a response. I've also tried this method without success:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($resp);
if (!$dom) {
    echo 'Error parsing document';
    exit;   
}

$simpleXML = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
echo $simpleXML;
return $simpleXML->NumCredits[0];
```

I have to be doing something wrong here but I can't quite figure out why it's so hard to parse this return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one element in your XML, so it is considered the document root:

```
$xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0"?><NumCredits>4</NumCredits>';
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($xml_string);
print_r($xml);
```

Will output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 4
)
```

Thus it can be accessed as `$xml[0];`

If you want to be able to access it by the element name, you will need to add a root element to your XML, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <NumCredits>4</NumCredits>
</root>
```

Once this document is parsed, you can access the value using `$xml->NumCredits;`

Comment: wow I really should have figured that out, thanks for alleviating my frustration!